# Injecting an image if the image doesn't already exist with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do the following:

- Check if a div contains the text "Correct Mistakes" if it does then it should:
- Check if the div contains an image and/or an image with a specific URL
- If the image exits and/or has a specific URL do nothing.
- If the image doesn't exist and/or doesn't have a specific URL then insert it after the h3 header tag

See the code below:

```
var imgURL = "https://i.imgur.com/umCv9Ck.png"

$('.container .modal .content').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('h3').text() == "Corrected Mistakes") {
        if ($(this).find('img').attr('src') != imgURL ) {
            console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'))
            $('<img alt="blue tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/umCv9Ck.png">').insertAfter(".container .modal .content h3");
        }
    }
});
```

Currently it's inserting the image over over and over, every time I run the code... it shouldn't because on the first run it adds the image so on future runs it should see this and not add it again.

I've tried using `:contains`, I've tried doing it in one statement as shown below

```
if ($(this).find('h3').text() == "Corrected Mistakes" && ($(this).find('img').attr('src') != imgURL) {}
```

But nothing I try seems to be working... it's going to be something simple that I am missing but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What's the result of the `console.log` statement that you added?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem, because the script in your question works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/xe4tzsLp/

Comment: @Andreas Interesting, I just tried with this code... and it does indeed work fine but if I use my actual URL it fails, because it contains: `?ts=1569456000&amp;ver=beta` It's not liking the `;` part in the URL

Answer (score 0):

I think part of that is the way your are using the selectors.  You did not post the HTML.  You can try what is below and edit accordingly.  Do you want to insert a new image element or replace the one that is there or change the src for the one that is there ?

var imgURL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgRBr.png";

```
$('.container.modal.content').each(function() {

    if ($(this).find('h3').text() == "Corrected Mistakes" && $(this).find('img').attr('src') !== imgURL) {
    $('<img alt="blue tile" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgRBr.png">').insertAfter($(this).find('h3'));

    }
});
```